# Putting PHP echo into a button's innerHTML doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a jQuery code like this:

```
$("#erase").click(function(){
        $("#erase").attr("disabled", "disabled"); // Prevent double-clicking
        $(this).html("Erasing...");
        $.post("erase.php", {target: $("#target").val(), criteria: $("#criteria").val()}, function(data){
            $(this).html(data); // Change the button's caption to whatever erase.php echoes.
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href = "index.php";
            }, 3000);
        });
```

The `target` and `criteria` are both HTML `input` tags and the button is declared with the `button` tag.
I was expecting these would happen when user clicks the button:

1. Button will be greyed out and its text will say 'Erasing...'
2. `erase.php` will be called via AJAX. `erase.php` will delete a row from a database, and takes several seconds to complete.
3. When the AJAX call is completed, the button text will be the output of `erase.php`. It will be either "Success" or "Failure"
4. After 3 seconds, user will be brought back to home page.

But in my case, step 3 fails. The button gets stuck in 'Erasing....' (The request *does* complete, however.)

---

Side note: I can't really think of a better title for this question. If you can come up with one for me. Please let me know in the comments. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Any error messages in console?

Comment: @Gowri There is no error in the console.

Comment: provide alert message to check response. `alert(data);` before `$(this).html(data); `

Comment: `console.log(this);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(this) inside of $.post is not the one that you had before. Try this way

```
$("#erase").click(function(){
    $("#erase").attr("disabled", "disabled"); // Prevent double-clicking
    $(this).html("Erasing...");
    $this = $(this);
    $.post("erase.php", {target: $("#target").val(),
           criteria: $("#criteria").val()}, function(data){
            $this.html(data); 
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href = "index.php";
            }, 3000);
        });
```

Comment: Cheery is correct. The "this" that you are trying referencing inside the callback function is out of scope. Once inside the new function, I believe what you are referencing by "this" is the function itself - which in JS is an object.

In cheery's example you are creating a new variable that is accessible lower in the scope.

In short, that this ain't what this used to be.